# Struts2 returns empty JSON in my AJAX call

Tags: java, json, struts2, model-driven, valuestack

I am struggling to get the JSON response from my Struts2 Action class, I think i am missing something. The following set up I have in my Project.

in my module level action definition , The configuration looks like :

```xml
<package name="customer" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">
   <action name="getCustomer" method="getCustomerBusiness" class="CustomerAction">
      <result type="json"/>
   </action>
</package>
```

in my Struts.xml I have

```xml
 <result-types>
    <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
 </result-types>

 <interceptors>
    <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
 </interceptors>
```

In My Action Class:

```java
  public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware,
        ServletResponseAware, ModelDriven {
    private List<CustomerBean> cpbeanList;

    public List<CustomerBean> getCpbeanList() {
        return cpbeanList;
    }

    public void setCpbeanList(List<CustomerBean> cpbeanList) {
        this.cpbeanList = cpbeanList;
    }

    public String getCustomerBusiness() {
        cpbeanList = new ArrayList<CustomerPortfolioBean>();
        // jsonData = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        CustomerBean cb1 = new CustomerPortfolioBean();
        cb1.setBusinessNm("IBM");
        cb1.setBusinessAddr("475 Anton Blvd");
        cb1.setBusinessPh("00000000");
        cb1.setBusinessCity("Costamesa");
        cb1.setBusinessStateCd("CA");
        c1.setBusinessZip("92704");

        similarly cb2, cb3, cb4.

        cpbeanList.add(cb1);
        cpbeanList.add(cb2);
        cpbeanList.add(cb3);
        cpbeanList.add(cb4);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

The JSON request `http://localhost:8080/customer/getCustomer` returns me empty array {} In the firebug ...I am able to see.

Also I am trying the out put as data table input in JQuery. which doesn't have row because of this.

Any one's help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused; where's your `getModel()`? Why re-define the "json" result type? Why doesn't `getCpbeanList()` return anything? Where's the package name in the action declaration? I hope it's not in the default package. Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes I am using Spring - Struts.

Comment: My public List<CustomerBean> getCpbeanList() {
  return cpbeanList;
 }

Comment: I didn't re-define, the  result-types definitions are in my struts.xml and action mapping is in my module level package.

Comment: Sure you did; the "json-default" package already defines the "json" result type.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question about your `getModel()` method.

Comment: I just removed the re-define part. but still no luck.

Comment: getModel() ??? why do i need that

Comment: Because your action implements `ModelDriven`. It won't even compile if you don't have it.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for that, the original implementation is I have a base action class CustomerBaseAction extends ActionSupport
       implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, ModelDriven , There I have public Object getModel(){
  return object;
 } my code CustomerAction extends CustomerBaseAction

Comment: If the base class does all that, why are you specifying it all over again in the subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action's superclass implements `ModelDriven`, hence so does your subclass. It's the model that will be serialized as JSON. If the model is empty, there's nothing to be serialized, so you get nothing back.

Your subclass should override `getModel()` and return the data you want to be serialized to JSON.

Comment: even I'm stuck with same problem, what changes required to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Since

- The **ModelDriven** Interceptor pushes the model on top of the ValueStack
- The **Json Result** serializes the whole action

and knowing that

- The **Json Result** has a `root` parameter that can be configured to restrict the Json serialization to a single element instead of that to the whole action's attributes
- The `root` parameter accepts **OGNL**

we can make the assumption that **it could be instructed to go backwards**,
 to be less restrictive (from a modelDriven point of view), instead of more restrictive as usual.

You could try to do something like

```xml
<result type="json">
    <param name="root">
        [1]
    </param>
</result>
```

or even better (since it is not guaranteed that `[1]` is the action)

```xml
<result type="json">
    <param name="root">
        #action
    </param>
</result>
```

to discover if it's actually possible to serialize the whole action while maintaining the Model on top of the ValueStack.

Comment: how can I access multiple fieldError as well as actionError, right now I am using  <param name="root">fieldErrors</param>

Comment: Just a note: `[1]` can be potentially dangerous because it might not point to action.

Comment: Sir can I have two root. <param name="root">fieldErrors</param> and <param name="root">actionErrors</param>

Comment: @piechuckerr: you can't have two roots. Have you tried, did it work ?  IF it works, just return the action, and in the page where before you consumed `fieldErrors`, (eg looping `data`), just write `data.fieldErrors`, `data.actionErrors`, etc... Since action and field errors are on the **base** class, they won't be serialized unless you set a parameter that will force the serialization on the whole hierarchy: `<param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>`. But apart from this being another question, let us know if the answer provided works :)

Comment: @AleksandrM absolutely, IF they both works, the second is the safe one :) I'll edit the answer if OP confirm this works

Comment: @piechuckerr thank you for the bounty. I've rejected the suggested edit because it was changing completely the meaning of the answer... I've not got what have you done, have you used #action or fieldErrors as root ? In the latter (that is not what I've described in my answer), please copy/paste that snippet in a new answer to this question, and I'll be happy to upvote it

Comment: I've used root. will you tell me any book/blog etc to understand struts2 thoroughly? btw Thank you for helping me 'again'.

Comment: I know you've used root :) I mean: what value has root ? #action ? Or fieldErrors ?